# PHP exec() não executa FFmpeg

Tags: php, windows, vídeo

O seguinte código funciona no prompt mas não funfa no php, por quê?

```
$ffmpeg = 'C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe';
$video = 'C:/absolute-path-para-o-video';
$output = 'C:/minha-pasta/thumbnail.jpg'; 
$cmd = '$ffmpeg -ss 3 -i $video -vf "select=gt(scene\,0.4)" -frames:v 5 -vsync vfr -vf fps=fps=1/600 $output &';

exec($cmd);
```

Funciona perfeitamente no Prompt do Windows, porém no PHP não roda e fica com esse erro no Apache

> '$ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>       operable program or batch file.

Comment: Use aspas duplas no `$cmd`

Comment: @Augusto e no select=gt... eu deixo com apostrofe ou deixo sem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é uma mensagem de erro **do Windows**, dizendo que não conseguiu executar **`$ffmpeg`**.

Percebi que você colocou o caminho completo para o executável na primeira linha, então creio que você só tenha esquecido de concatenar a variável com o resto do comando.

Aliás, as variáveis `$video` e `$output` também estão indo como literais para o comando

Também é importante deixar a variável `$video` dentro de aspas duplas, pra não dar erro caso tenha espaços no caminho do arquivo.

```
$cmd = $ffmpeg. ' -ss 3 -i "' . $video . '" -vf "select=gt(scene\,0.4)" -frames:v 5 -vsync vfr -vf fps=fps=1/600 ' . $output . ' &';
```

Comment: Obrigado, agora funcionou perfeitamente bem e sem erros, em praticamente todos os tutoriais que achei nenhum especificava que as variáveis tinha que ser concatenadas